# Implementing an absolute value function in C

Tags: microcontroller, c, math

I am implementing a function to find the absolute value like this:

```
uint16_t absolute_value(int16_t n)
{
  int16_t mask = n >> 15;
  return ((n+mask)^mask);
}
```

Is it any quicker than just doing a simple multiply by -1 if less than 0?

This code is on a microprocessor where speed is everything.

Comment: Multiplying by -1 is just bitwise inversion and adding 1. Any decent compiler will know this and generate this code instead of a multiply. Your code might be faster (depending on architecture) because it doesn't branch.

Comment: Probably the most bang for the buck is making it a macro and not a function call, since the call overhead is bigger than the work you do in the function. That's what stdlib.h will typically take care off as well.

Comment: @Hilmar Preprocessor macros are evil. Much better would be an inline function, so the compiler can do type checking.

Comment: @Hilmar Err, no. Welcome to the new millennium, we have function inlining here. Unless of course you are stuck with a 1980s/1990s compiler.

Comment: @Lundin right. The same for many other micro-optimisations, like this bitmask stuff here. In fact, there are cases where a modern compiler will transform a piece of manually “optimised” code back into high-level instructions, knowing that these are actually faster on the target processor. — Still, I suppose for many microcontrollers you'll have even today a much dumber compiler than the one you'd use for x86-64 or ARM. So in some cases it may be necessary to at least add the `inline` annotation by hand to get the desired performance, if not gnarlier bit-twiddling or even CPP macros.

Answer (score 11):

The standard C library is providing the optimized solutions for many problems with considerations based on the architecture, compiler in use and others. The `abs()` function defined in `stdlib.h` is one of these, and it is used for your purpose exactly. To emphasize the point, here is ARM compiler result when using `abs` vs a version of a homebrew `abs`: https://arm.godbolt.org/z/aO7t1n

Paste:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(111);
    int x = rand() - 200;
    printf("%d\n", abs(x));
}
```

results in

```
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     r0, #111
        bl      srand
        bl      rand
        sub     r1, r0, #200
        cmp     r1, #0
        rsblt   r1, r1, #0
        ldr     r0, .L4
        bl      printf
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L4:
        .word   .LC0
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%d\012\000"
```

And

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_abs(int x)
{
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(111);
    int x = rand() - 200;
    printf("%d\n", my_abs(x));
}
```

results in

```
my_abs:
        cmp     r0, #0
        rsblt   r0, r0, #0
        bx      lr
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     r0, #111
        bl      srand
        bl      rand
        sub     r1, r0, #200
        cmp     r1, #0
        rsblt   r1, r1, #0
        ldr     r0, .L5
        bl      printf
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L5:
        .word   .LC0
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%d\012\000"
```

Notice that the `main` code is identical (only a label name is different) in both programs as `my_abs` got inlined, and its implementation is the same as the standard one.

Comment: Your final comment is perfect. Since the result is know at compile time, the codes do not actually calculate the abs.

Comment: @vangelo Are you saying I have cheated? :) Well, let me get another example

Comment: Of course not! I'm just pointing out that both codes already show the result in the assembly. :)

Comment: @vangelo OK, then I will leave it to the reader :) Which is by the way another thing. If `my_abs` was defined in a separate translation unit (source file), the compiler would not know what it does and won't be able to optimize it to a compile-time result. But with standard `abs` it always knows it.

Comment: Oh well. Here it is: https://arm.godbolt.org/z/AIzLre One can notice there is no function call at all when using `abs`.

Comment: Yes, you have cheated. Letting the compiler do the calculation tells us nothing.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Does the link in the previous comment helps it? By the way, you think my answer is any wrong? Unhelpful?

Comment: Yes, I think it is unhelpful. You might as well have compared two versions of "printf("%d",22);" Also, you changed the datatypes of the function and its parameter. Whether or not you get a function call for my_abs() depends on how you have declared it...it should be declared inline and static.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson `abs` is defined as `int abs(int);`. The same types, the same definition according to http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.6.1 .No `inline`, no `static`. So let's compare oranges to oranges. I will change the sample code, even though it was just an illustration to the actual answer which is the first paragraph.

Comment: But the OP specified `int16_t` and `uint16_t` types, which may or may not be equivalent to `int`. The question was really about optimizing the **implementation** of an absolute value function, and I think you need to keep all other factors the same (e.g. inline functions) if that is the intent of the question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I see your point. Unfortunately I afraid I won't be able to push it into the answer as we are getting here into the platform specifics. For example on ARM it's the `rsblt` who is doing most of the work, which might not be available elsewhere.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why the compiler wouldn't inline your custom abs but only the library one. This is some compiler hiccup. Add `inline` to your godbolt and you'll observe identical machine code in either case. https://arm.godbolt.org/z/nsEq_8  So all you have proven with this code is that one particular gcc ARM compiler does inlining poorly.

Comment: Actually, the missed optimization is probably related to the function getting external linkage. Making it `static` results in correct inlining as well. In either case, this is all a poor rationale of why we shouldn't write homebrewed `abs`.

Comment: @Lundin You have to write your own function if the standard libraries don't support your non-standard datatypes. And as I mentioned earlier, the `static` attribute indicates that the function won't be used in another compilation unit.

Comment: @Lundin My goal was not to prove anything. My answer is in the first paragraph and is a commonly established fact rarely questioned. The code is for illustration only and providing the reader the method of experimenting.

Comment: ([*its* it is](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s) (last sentence))

Answer (score 3):

The speed of a given solution will depend greatly on the architecture, but in C I would say

```
return (n > 0 ? n : -n);
```

and let the compiler figure out the best solution.

EDIT: @jonk points out correctly that this will fail for the most-negative possible value of n, assuming that two's-complement arithmetic is used.

Yes, my solution has a conditional branch, but yours has an arithmetic operator and two bitwise operators. Can your microcontroller shift 15 places in a single clock?

Comment: This is basically just to agree. If a fully portable solution is desirable, do it simple, as you suggested. If the best/shortest/fastest option is needed, it will depend on your processor/compiler and it is very likely that the standard (or non-standard) library will provide the best code.

Comment: @vangelo Just one minor point...I think that the functions in stdlib are defined for int rather than int16_t or uint16_t. The size of an int may be 32 bits, which could influence speed. But you are correct that if an appropriate library function is available it is best to use it.

Comment: I agree. This is why I also mentioned non-standard. It is not uncommon that "extensions" are available and in fact quite common with micro-controllers.

Comment: "Can your microcontroller shift 15 places in a single clock?" I take it you mean single instruction. Yes, most cores can do that.

Comment: Incidentally, a non-braindead compiler won't use a conditional branch for this. First of all it sees that whole expression and says "oh, you're trying to find the absolute value, I've got some pre-written code for that." But even if it didn't do that, it would say "Oh, that's a good opportunity for a CMOV."

Comment: @Lundin Yes, **most** can but some can not. No, I didn't mean a single instruction...old microcoded machines had instructions that would do multiple bit shifts but the microcode took many clock cycles, and the OP cares about speed.

Comment: @Sneftel No hablo "CMOV". We weren't assuming a specific architecture, so even the best compiler may need to use a conditional instruction. And remember, we were talking about taking the absolute value of a non-standard datatype so the compiler may not have seen such a function before.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Most cores have very few single cycle instructions. But nowadays they all have pipe-lining and the more high end ones have instruction pre-fetch cache etc.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson :-) Take a look at what various compilers use for various platforms. The results may surprise you. Turns out every architecture has fun tricks. (And nobody uses a sequential shifter anymore.)

Comment: @Sneftel The AVR architecture shift instructions shift just one bit at a time, so clearly we can't say "nobody".

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of subtle details in using C. Given your comment about speed, it is probably worth your time to try out various options and see which produces better assembly code results. Ask the compiler to generate assembly code and then read it. (This doesn't always catch the reality, though. Some compilers leave certain replacements to the linker step.) Or use the machine code and a disassembler and just look. (That always works.) It's not hard to do once you've worked out the steps in your situation.

Let me just suggest some options to consider. Perhaps that's the best I can do. (I'm assuming below that you don't want to take the absolute function of a constant, since there is an obvious "code time" solution for that case.)

1. The abs() function that's available for your C compiler may very well be implemented in-line with the compiler. (Microsoft's x86 C compiler certainly does this.) If this is already handled within the compiler, looking at the machine code will tell you what you need to know. Sometimes, the assembly output isn't a sufficient test since some compilers will leave this optimization step to the linker process, instead. In those cases, you will have no choice but to examine the final machine code product.
2. You can attempt to use the method you already mentioned (using an **if** statement or using the trinary ? operator.) Again, I've seen versions of Microsoft's C compiler that will eat these perfectly well and generate exactly the same case as if you'd used their in-line abs() version -- which for some targets will generate code without any branching involved and taking two or three instructions.
3. You can use the method you've coded up (which is dependent on your word size.) You've coded one method: \$\left(n+mask\right)\, \text{^}\, mask\$.
4. You could try: \$\left(n\, \text{^}\, mask\right)-mask\$.
5. You could try: \$n-\left(\left[n << 1\right]\, \&\: mask\right)\$ or \$n-\left(2\,n\, \&\: mask\right)\$ or \$n-\left(\left[n+n\right]\, \&\: mask\right)\$.

There are other options if you have a fast multiply for +1 or -1 (sometimes, that's easy.)

Be wary of, and follow, the C standards. Often, operations on negative signed values are undefined. They may behave as expected. But that behavior may not be portable or guaranteed.

As a final note, if you intend on writing a function in C it may pay to provide the compiler hint to make it an inline function.

Comment: @ThePhoton There's already a corner case in (n > 0 ? n : -n). The case where n is the maximal negative value (which that will return unchanged.) I was mostly trying to help list out as many different things to try with the compiler. By the way, which corner case are you considering?

Comment: I think shifting a signed datatype left (`n << 1`) is undefined behavior for ANSI C. Multiplying a fixed-width datatype by 2 also risks silent integer overflow.

Comment: @jonk good point on the maximal negative corner case. But this is the behavior even for the standard function right?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I just checked Harbison and Steele. In the left shift case C defines the behavior regardless of type and it is portable. However, you are right to be worried, in the right shift case, where the C compiler is permitted two different behaviors and it is not portable.

Comment: @jonk The left shift for negative value is undefined per the standard http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4 . Worth noting that the standard `abs` is undefined for the most negative value as well, so it is on par with `x < 0 ? -x : x` solution.

Comment: @EugeneSh. 7.21.6.1 "If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined." So I agree on the maximal negative value treatment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If the left shift for negative values is undefined now, then that supercedes my Harbison and Steele textbook.

Comment: @jonk Well... When it comes to C then only the standard is credible enough.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Agreed on that point. (Harbison and Steele were active compiler writers and are usually to be trusted. But not always, it seems.) Thanks for the link. (I'll have to do some more diligence.)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've added a note about being aware that the C standard may leave certain operations as undefined for negative signed values.